# Xamarin Forms - Geofencing with Shiny not triggering when in geofence

Tags: xamarin.forms, shiny, notifications, geolocation, geofencing

I have created a xamarin forms application and one of the requirements is as follows: The user should be able to press a button and create a geofence. When the geofence is created, the application constantly checks if the user is in a geofence. It that's true, the mobile app should show a notification sayinf: you have entered geofence.

I use Shiny to implement the feature based on this tutorial: "https://allancritchie.net/posts/shiny-geofencing".

But the problem is that it isn't doing anything. I have set the geofence 50 meters from my house, and the radius for checking to 200 meter, so when I build the app, a couple of seconds/minuts I should receive a nofitication right? Or do I need to go out of the fence first and then in? How can I fix this issue...

my code:

```
            // shiny doesn't usually manage your viewmodels, so we'll do this for now
        var geofences = ShinyHost.Resolve<IGeofenceManager>();
        var notifications = ShinyHost.Resolve<INotificationManager>();

        Register = new Command(async () =>
        {
            // this is really only required on iOS, but do it to be safe
            var access = await notifications.RequestAccess();
            if (access == AccessState.Available)
            {
                await geofences.StartMonitoring(new GeofenceRegion(
                    "CN Tower - Toronto, Canada",
                    new Position(52.079779, 4.337133),
                    Distance.FromMeters(200)
                )
                {
                    NotifyOnEntry = true,
                    NotifyOnExit = true,
                    SingleUse = false
                });
            }
        });



public class GeofenceDelegate : IGeofenceDelegate
{
    private readonly INotificationManager _notifications;

    public GeofenceDelegate(INotificationManager notifications)
    {
        _notifications = notifications;
    }

    public async Task OnStatusChanged(GeofenceState newStatus, GeofenceRegion region)
    {
        if (newStatus == GeofenceState.Entered)
        {
            await GeofenceEntered(region);
        }
        else if (newStatus == GeofenceState.Exited)
        {
            await GeofenceLeft(region);
        }
    }

}
```

I have exactly the same code as the tutorial, and the geofence is created when I click a button if I debug it. So everything looks fine to me..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and just assumed that when you start inside a fence it won't recognize you as entering/or exiting since you are already inside it.

I had to walk out/in of the created fence to trigger the 'OnStatusChanged' method.

Important to note is, that it wouldn't enter the method unless my app activated the phones GPS-system (e.g. re-requesting the current position periodically), but im not sure if that is caused by my old ass phone (*running Android6.1*) or if it is mend to work that way.

Also note, that i didn't use the shiny.notifications and just showed a popup when the method was run (for testing purposes) like this:

```
public async Task OnStatusChanged(GeofenceState newStatus, GeofenceRegion region)
{
     await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(newStatus.ToString(), $"{region.Identifier}", "Ok");
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Very werid, In the end I chose not to use Shiny anymore. Their documentation isn't up to date and the samples arn't great aswell..

Comment: true... have you used another framework, or have you done everything on your own?

Comment: I have used geolocator plugin. Not I feth the users location and compare it with another location, when the value is lower than a treshhold, the user is in a geofence. I don't know if this is a really good solution because of battery consumption..